# Обработка исключения при добавлении параметра в Delphi7 и условие

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

второй вариант условие

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
reg:Tregistry;
begin
try
reg:=TRegistry.Create;    // начало
reg.RootKey := HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;        // корень
reg.OpenKey('Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies', true);
reg.WriteInteger('NoDriveTypeAutoRun', 16895);
except
on Exception do {showmessage('Невозможно добавить параметр')}//не выполняеться при нормальном доступе к реестру и выполняеться при отмене доступа
begin
showmessage ('В доступе отказано');
reg.CloseKey; // Закрыли и освободили и идём дальше
FreeAndNil(reg);
end;
end;
FreeAndNil(reg);

showmessage ('первый параметр добавлен'); // всегда выполняется как исправить?
end;
end.
```

Comment: При запуске программы в нормальном режиме всё работает штатно а если запустить её в CORE FORCE TEHNOLOGY это такой фаервол в режиме RUN WITH SECURITY PROFILE c ограничением этой моей программы что либо делать в системе вылезает ошибка из моей проги на DELPHI7 ошибка -  Failed to set data for 'NoDriveTypeAutoRun' как перехватить это сообщение Exception - исключением с выводом сообщения о невозможности добавления параметра в реестр.

Comment: Ща поясню для чего это - это для того если у пользователя антивирус и он запрещает сторонним программам залезать реестр то должно высветиться корректное сообщение с предложением отключить антивирус или подобное, что бы пользователь знал что дальше ему делать.  И напоследок ошибки при компиляции на всякий случай 
[Error] SAK.pas(40): Statement expected, but expression of type 'Class reference' found
[Error] SAK.pas(47): Declaration expected but identifier 'reg' found
[Error] SAK.pas(56): '.' expected but ';' found
[Fatal Error] sak.dpr(5): Could not compile used unit 'SAK.pas'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вроде правильно тебя понял

Между try и except пишем код в котором может возникнуть исключительная ситуация, в блоке except по end; что будем делать если исключительная ситуация возникла.

[Код здесь](http://pastebin.com/jCzJP5jB)

Comment: блин не получается нормально код оформить(

Comment: ща буду пробывать

Comment: давай. удачи

Comment: Код работает но есть один нюанс в доступе отказано срабатывает при запрете доступа, и после этого срабатывает моя ложная команда что параметр добавлен, когда доступ разрешён всё работает корректно параметр добавлен доступ запрещён стабатывает и запрещён и добавлен что за условие нужно в исключении исходник выложу в ответе на свой вопрос .

Comment: http://pastebin.com/rMrNyG2U

Смысл такой:
Если в процессе записи данных в реестр произойдет исключительная ситуация то выполнение программы перейдет в блок except. В случае если не возникнет исключительной ситуации выполнение программы дойдет до строки с выводом сообщения об успешности выполненной операции.